# Show picture in fullscreen and admit zoom in/out

Tags: android, android-imageview

My app recover some pictures from a server (base64 encoded) then show it into an ImageView by create a bitmap from encoded string of picture. Now, i would show (after touch on ImageView ) picture in full screen, and admit user to zoom in/out on picuture (like android stock gallery). How can i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement zoom effect for image view in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399296/how-to-implement-zoom-effect-for-image-view-in-android)

Comment: take a look at this library: https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom
It can do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think this thread will answer most of your question(s), and even provides some example code:

[Android imageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)