# ImageView zooming in android through code

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, effect

I am developing Android application for book. I create total images for book is one hundred. In the app two buttons present one is previous button and second is next button. The previous button and next move images forward and back correctly. But now I want to implement zooming effect for image. But the text are some smalls not seen correctly. Please help. Thank you

Comment: `But the text are some smalls not seen correctly` what is this? For zoom you can find custom imageview on internet that can zoom images on tap.

Comment: I'd use this library: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Below are the options available for implementing zoom in-out effect in android Imageview.

1. [How to implement zoom effect for image view in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399296/how-to-implement-zoom-effect-for-image-view-in-android)
2. [Android imageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)
3. https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: How we use the third option ?

Comment: In your build.gradle add dependency. compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:latest.release.here' then inside your code us can use

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage
Much better than the offered alternatives here IMHO